# C# /ASP.NET MVC Unit Testing: Nunit - Assert Custom SQL Exception

Tags: c#, sql, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I am writing unit tests for the first time for an existing project.

At this point I am focusing on methods that call our DataAccessLayer

I have a Method:

```
public static bool UpdateRequestCancelledStatus(
  string requestId, 
  string comment, 
  bool startManualWork
)
```

This method calls a stored procedure, that updates a record based on requestId.

Since I can't rely on any data being available, I generate a blank requestId:

```
string requestId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
```

It is impossible for this request to exist in the table. 
The stored procedure throws back a custom exception error.

I want to Assert that this error is thrown. I'm using the code below, but, the unit test if failing because it's throwing a custom sql error, and I'm expecting and sqlexception. How can I modify this to expect the custom sql error.

[image]

```
[Test]
        public void UpdateRequestCancelledStatus()
        {

            string requestId =  Guid.Empty.ToString();
            string comment = "Comment from Unit Test";
            bool startManualWork = false;
            var ex = Assert.Throws<SqlException>(() => nsBusSrvData.RequestMaintenance.OrderDetails.UpdateRequestCancelledStatus(requestId, comment, startManualWork));
            Assert.IsNotNull(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Can you enlarge your custom exception?

Comment: Fail: Custom Sql Server Error - Error No = 547 , Procedure Name = Genomics.InsertEvent , Error Line = 55 , SqlErrorLogIdn = 18528 , Error Message = The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_RequestToEvent_Request". The conflict occurred in database "xxxxxxx", table "Genomics.Request", column 'Id'.
  Expected: <System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException>
  But was:  null

Comment: Well there's a problem with your SP or the arguments you pass it, but why can't you specify this exception in your unit test?

Comment: That is my question, how can I specify the exception. The issue is with the ID im passing in. I have know way of knowing if there are records on the table. So I pass a value that throws an exception, verifying that the stored procedure was called correctly. I just need to know how specify the exception in my test.

Comment: You should substitute `SqlException` in `Assert.Throws<SqlException>` with the exception you get

Comment: The thing to do would be to provide your data access layer with a mock for its database. By providing it with either a connection to a test database whose contents are completely under your control; or mocking out the db provider dll using shims or some other form of mocking.